# Can't use Holo themes with ActionBarActivity child (correct API chosen)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I'm going through the tutorial at developers.android.com and I had problems with styling the action bar. I use the newest SDK (the bundle with Eclipse).

Say, that in values-v14/styles.xml I have

```
<style name="MessageTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

I've tried all the variations of that that I could find. Tried without DarkActionBar in values-v11 as well.
It compiles fine but when I open activity styled as such, app crashes and logcat says

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Like I said, API is set correctly. The target one in project properties (API 19) and android:minSdkVersion="14" in the manifest (tried higher as well).

Now, my activity extends ActionBarActivity (that's how the file was generated). If I make it extend Activity instead, then Holo works fine. That's an answer I found, but I don't understand why that works. What exactly is the difference between ActionBarActivity and Activity that makes this works and is this some hack or is it supposed to be done this way?
Also, that works fine with my additional Activity. If I try to this with the main activity from the tutorial, it doesn't compile because 2 methods used there are undefined - getSupportActionBar and getSupportFragmentManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a compatibility library, so to style a support actionBar you need your theme to be descendant of appCompat.

Try this:

```
<style name="Theme.whatever" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

If you are still a little lost, you can generate your theme with this tool: [ActionBar style generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) and take a look how it's done.

**Edit:**

Check this out, also: [Styling the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

See "For Android 2.1 and higher"

About the difference between Activity and ActionBarActivity...

As far as I know, you extend ActionBarActiviy if you need to have an action bar while targeting lower than 3.0 android versions. That's why you are having troubles with actionBar or supportActionBar depending on what kind of activity you are coding.

So, to summarize, when working with Acivity call [actionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html), but If you are extending ActionBarActivity you should call SupportActionBar. For instance: getSupportActionBar().

More info you could use: [Support Library Features](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html)

**Edit 2:** Android is yelling at you because your are trying to use appCompat features. To avoid this in your particular instance, all you need to do is NOT extending ActionBarActivity, but coding regular Activities. Then use ActionBar features as normally you would do.

**Edit 3 and probably last:**

Let's guess you are using holo as theme, and you are coding a regular Acitivty for API 11 and above. In this case you are not extending ActionBarActiviy, so you don't have to do anything special. That's ok, right? but now, you want the same thing to work for API versions lower than 11 and here comes your real problem. To make that happen you must extend ActionBarActivity, but you didn't. So your only way out (as far as I know) is to have another activity that extends ActionBarActivity, and somehow detect with code, which version of android is running, in order to execute the right code (this is, which class you of the two you should take advantage of) so your app would be able to avoid crashing.

Thats why I think using only appComapt is a nice solution, assuming you don't really need to use holo. But, if you truly want to make things that way...

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
     // Use a regular Activity class for API 11 and above.
}
else{
    // Use an activity extending ActionBarActivity. Have in mind that here you would be calling a supportActionBar instead of a regular ActionBar.
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not very helpful. I know I have to that for some reason, it basically says so in logcat. The point is - I don't want to (I want to use Holo as in the tutorial) and I don't understand why it claims I should use it (I don't use a compatibility library, at least I don't intentionally and in previous examples from the tutorial I didn't have to use the code for Support Library). How do I turn off the compatibility library?

Comment: Ok, I have edited my own answer. If you don't want to target lower than 3.0 android devices with actionBar (and I'm assuming you don't because of your minSdk version), all you need to do is NOT extending ActionBarActivity anymore. Just use Activity.

Comment: Pardon me. Just to make it clear. When extending ActionBarActivity you are actually using a support library. Check your imports and look for android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

Comment: Thanks. So, there's no way to have an action bar on devices with API below 11 (i.e. use ActionBarActivity) and use Holo on devices that can do it? What's the point of values-v14 then? Has something been changed in that regard recently? In the tutorial the main activity extends ActionBarActivity, yet it's supposed to use Holo.

Comment: I don't think so, but could you please link that tutorial?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html 
You can see that activities extend ActionBarActivity for example here - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: In the first tutorial you have linked you can see that they are using supportActionBar (A.K.A. compatibility library feature), and in the second one you should look carefully. See the difference between 3.0 and above, and lower than 3.0. 3.0 and above uses holo, right. But lower doesn't. It uses Theme.AppCompat instead. Now, if you are worried because of your app look and feel, don't be. AppCompat has a light version and a dark version, just like holo.

Comment: I'm not worried about the looks, I'm just trying to understand what they screw up in the tutorial. It seems they forget to mention to change the parent class to use Holo. 
But then again, If I can't use Holo in values-v14/styles.xml while adding action bar for older API via Support Library and ActionBarActivity that just seems strange since they have files for styles in different API versions.

Comment: I don't think they did anything wrong in that tutorial. You can do what you say about v14. That is possible. The only problem is that you'll have to deal with versions while coding. That's all. My latest explanation might not been good enough. If that is so, I apologize, and I think that's all I can tell you about all of this.

Comment: OK, now You lost me. If I can do what I say about v14 (i.e. use Holo there while still using ActionBarActivity) and they did nothing wrong in the tutorial (i.e. there's no need to change the parent class to Activity in order to use Holo) then... how I can do that? That's the whole point of my question - if I try and do as the tutorial says, the app crashes.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't mean confusing you. Check my 3rd edit. I cannot explain in this comment due to character limit.